# does php-curl support 'PATCH'?

Tags: php, curl

I'm using php and curl to test rest api, specifically 'PATCH'. 
When I run my below code, i get The output is:{"code":"InvalidContent","message":"Invalid JSON: Unexpected token \n"}

what am i missing? can we do curl PATCH over https? the access token I've is valid and works for all the other apis.

I've the following code:

```
<?php

     $url = 'https://a-q.abc.co/docs/<ean>';

     $ch = curl_init($url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PATCH" ); 
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  
     array('Authorization: Bearer <access_token>=', 'Accept-Version: ~1','Content-Type: application/json')); 
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
     curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'{"title": "
     script Ran", "authors":[{"firstName":"12344", "lastName":"dddd"}],"description":"Script Document"}');
     $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if(!CURL_ERROR($ch)){
        echo"\n The output is:".$response;
    }else{
        echo "\n Fetch failed ".curl_error($ch);
        exit;
    }

  curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: Is the (actual) `\n` in the `title`'s value (so just before `script ran`) intentional? Seems to me a perfect cause of the error you're seeing.

Comment: Thank you Roblll.. i feel so stupid now.. i had the soft warp on but after doing some edits i lost that. I was breaking my head yesterday wondering what is going on..... :(